# Refresh Web Page only once after submitting the form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to try to refresh the page after submitting the form but i can not find the solution how to refresh the web page using php.
Please help me out.

Comment: Redirect to same page!! `header('Location:your-current-page.php');`

Comment: I see your 'question' refers to "the form". We don't know it. Can we have a look? ..and also tell us what are you trying to do.

Comment: Your current question is unclear. Normally a form submit would 'refresh' the page it is submitted to. Although I would not call this a refresh. Normally you should have processed the form content before you start rendering the page.

Comment: are you using AJAX to submit form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After submit you can call :

```
header("Refresh:0");
```

It refreshes your current page. Or give url to redirect new page.

```
header("Refresh:0; url=desirepage.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger a `window.location.reload()` in the success callback of your AJAX form submit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use header function of PHP.
It is used to redirect the page. you want to refresh.So, you can redirect to the same page.

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: I think that it will not help as according to tags the form is posted by AJAX request....

Comment: @Zeusarm: he mentioned there "..solution how to refresh the web page using php."

Comment: we both understand that if it general post then there is no need to refresh the page as the page is loaded automatically after posting the form

Comment: @Zeusarm : Yes! That's right. But, what he asked answered that. As he not provided the code.

Comment: but after form post, if we manually refresh the page, browser will ask for submission.. to get rid of that we need to redirect to same page as solution!